# Dependency problems while updating kernel 6.1.0-18

Tags: linux-kernel, dpkg

I'm only one week Debian 12 user and, to be honest, it's already my 3rd try installing to properly. Today I was trying to configure my wifi adapter TP-Link Archer T4U Plus AC1300 installing drivers on it. Firstly I was following this instruction: https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702 and it actually helped me while previous installation of Debian everything went wrong this time.
So, while struggling with it, I've found this repository https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU. After doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` I've noticed interesting new 6.1.0-18 kernel module which was cpnflicting with my `88x2bu` and `nvidia-current/525.147.05` drivers. I was trying to uninstall the first one with remove-driver.sh in copied repo folder but problem still appears. That is output while doing any `sudo apt install` or `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Setting up linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 (6.1.76-1) ...
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-18-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.1.0-18-amd64.
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=6.1.0-18-amd64...^[.......(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/88x2bu/1.1/build/make.log for more information.
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
env NV_VERBOSE=1 make -j36 modules KERNEL_UNAME=6.1.0-18-amd64............(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/525.147.05/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 (6.1.76-1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.1.0-18-amd64.
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=6.1.0-18-amd64............(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/88x2bu/1.1/build/make.log for more information.
Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.1/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
env NV_VERBOSE=1 make -j36 modules KERNEL_UNAME=6.1.0-18-amd64............(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/525.147.05/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 (= 6.1.76-1); however:
  Package linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
 linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 (= 6.1.76-1); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.14.1-4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.36-9+deb12u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64
 linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do: sudo apt install or sudo apt remove
Expected: NOT new kernel autoinstall

Answer (score 5):

I fixed mine by uninstalling all NVIDIA drivers. **Backup your system before trying though.**

```
# apt purge "*nvidia*"
systemctl reboot
```

https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Uninstallation

Answer (score 2):

i simply uninstalled linux image 6.1.18 and headers working on 6.1.17

Comment: I think this is the solution I will go with. Last time I removed Nvidia drivers trashed my system requiring a full re-install.

Answer (score 1):

I got that Issue when i try to update Debian 12....
Work for me:

```
# apt purge "*nvidia*"
sudo apt autoremove
systemctl reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this on my debian 12 and it worked for me:
1.Use synaptic to search for linux-image-6.1.18-amd64 and select for complete removal. and apply
2. run sudo apt autoremove
3. run sudo update-grub2
4. reboot - It should reboot to the 6.1.17 kernel. NVIDIA drivers still work.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to also remove the header packages for the same kernel version.

Answer (score 1):

Linux 6.1.76 (included in the latest Debian bookworm update) broke compilation of the non-free nvidia kernel module.

see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1063675

The solution may be to uninstall your nvidia drivers in favor of the Nouveau Driver, or downgrade your Linux image/headers back to the previous version

Answer (score -1):

I experience the same issue. Debian Stable changes its minor version and is breaking updates AGAIN. Last time, it was a kernel update that could cause data loss in ext4. Not so stable I would say. It seems they don't check updates properly.

Comment: So, mb don't you know how to disable this kernel autoinstall? I still can install packages but these errors annoy a bit.

Comment: It is an option. yes.